# How jquery data works after on click and off click?

Tags: jquery

I found this code on jquery

```
var $p = jQuery("p"), p = $p[0];
$p.append(jQuery.hasData(p)+" "); /* false */

$.data(p, "testing", 123);
$p.append(jQuery.hasData(p)+" "); /* true*/

$.removeData(p, "testing");
$p.append(jQuery.hasData(p)+" "); /* false */

$p.on('click', function() {});
$p.append(jQuery.hasData(p)+" "); /* true */-------------
                                                        |
$p.off('click');                                        |-->> couldn't understand
$p.append(jQuery.hasData(p)+" "); /* false */-----------|
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94Jyk/)

Comment: could be because the event handlers are stored as data on the element... checkout `$._data(p)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny There's nothing instead of these codes.

Comment: look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Vz7c/2/ the event handlers are registered as data in an internal data reference

Comment: As the docs says "Note that jQuery's event system uses the jQuery data API to store event handlers. Therefore, binding an event to an element using .on(), .bind(), .live(), .delegate(), or one of the shorthand event methods also associates a data object with that element."